# Android Inapp Version 3 error

Tags: android, google-play

Hello I am new In android I am Implementing In-App Version 3 I carefully read the Readme of version 3
When I start my app It shows an Error that is
Error:Problem setting up in -app billing : lbResult :Error checking for billing v3 support.
(response:3:Billing Unavailable)
I am using micromax_A70  and google play store version 3.10.10

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try clearing the cache and data of the Google Play Store, and then again start google play store ..Hope it works for you..

Comment: Package name is also same but I not publish App

Comment: I do All possible things like  in Security.java, the public key should be same as the one in the Android Market account

the version of the Market application in the Device should be 2.3.4 or higher

the device you use for testing must run a standard version of the Android 1.6 or later

the application being tested must be uploaded as draft, in the Android market, and must be signed


the device must have a something@gmail.com account as its primary account and this account should be defined as a test account in the Android market

Comment: Checklist - just to be sure you know this: The public key comes from the Developer Console's data for the draft app; it is not the public key that corresponds to the private key the developer account uses for signing the app.  The test account must not be the same as the main developer account.  You must have included the billing permission in your manifest.  You refer at various times to the Android Market app but the Google Play app is the only one that supports in-app billing v3.

Comment: @curl I am not getting Private key from my developer account where this key is specififed in developer account or how to genrate this key and is it necessary to sign in first in my device using test account

Comment: Clearing the cache of play store works for me. Thanks.