# What are the possibilities to get this error code 3 in InApp purchase?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am using InApp V3 code for in-app purchases in my application , i am getting this error `BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_BILLING_UNAVAILABLE` and `error value :3` when Google account is not available in device. I want to know is there any other possibilities to get this error, because when i get this error i need show a popup to the user with some data. If this is causing because of Google account not available on device i will show the dialog with related text. this is the code i am using

```
mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
    public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {              
        if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                // error here               
            return;
        }
    }
});
```

this is the error `Error checking for billing v3 support. (response: 3:Billing Unavailable)`

Comment: Why did you accept the answer from Carlos Robles while it does not answer the question?

Comment: I'm having this error when there isn't any account registered in the device, did you find a way to prompt the user to log in with her Google account?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As we can see directly in the [code of the setup](https://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/source/browse/v3/src/com/example/android/trivialdrivesample/util/IabHelper.java?r=5f6b7abfd0534acd5bfc7c14436f4500c99e0358#264) of the IabHElper of the sample provided by Google, the error means:

> "Billing service unavailable on device."

As you can read [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html) that error means

```
Billing API version is not supported for the type requested
```

This is the In-app Billing Reference (IAB Version 3), so the error means that the IAB v3 is not installed on the device.

Actually this means that the user has a Google account, and probably also an in-app billing service, but it doesn't have the last version. This happens in old devices, and where the user never updates anything. It used to be devices where you can see the old Market app instead of the Play app.

So the error you have to show to the user, and the test that you have to perform is not if the device has a Google account, but if it has the Google Play services installed and properly updated.

If you look for the code in all the library SDK, and the helper classes provided by google, the only place where we can find that exactly in the function that you are calling: the `startSetup` of the `IabHelper` class

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(
                "com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND");
        if (!mContext.getPackageManager().queryIntentServices(serviceIntent, 0)
                .isEmpty()) {
            // service available to handle that Intent
            mContext.bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConn,
                    Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        } else {
            // no service available to handle that Intent
            mServiceConn=null;
            if (listener != null) {
                listener.onIabSetupFinished(new IabResult(
                        BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_BILLING_UNAVAILABLE,
                        "Billing service unavailable on device."));
            }
        }
```

This means that the app couldn't connect to the service in the device, **since the package manager doesn't even know it**. That's the only option that can trigger that error. And what does it mean that it couldn't connect to the service? It means one of these:

- The device doesn't have the service installed.
- It has an old version, since we know that the latest versions of play store, uses the IAB v3.

So, your error only can mean one of these, that for you means that you have to show a message to the user like "You don't have Google Play services installed, or you have to update it". And there are no other possibilities for getting that error.

**But, if you want to make it easier for the users, you can say the they need to update the Google Play App to the last version**. And that will make everything work like a charm.

Comment: Can i depends on this error to show popup as "user need to add google account in device"

Comment: you could, but the proper message should be that the device needs the google account, and download the last version of google play services.

Comment: is there any other possibilities to get this error other than this

Comment: What you mean of it "error means that the IAB v3 is not installed on the device.". How user can install it?

Comment: it should NOT be, since this is an error that you are getting directly from the libraries that you add to your project, http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html, that are trying to comunicate with the play services. So that response code is a response code sent by IAB3, and thats the only meaning of that code

Comment: if the error is that the user doesnt has it, it should get solved updating play services in the device. if the problem is that the app itself is using the old libraries, the app code has to be updated, following this guide: http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview.html#migration, but as far as i know the app is using v3 already

Comment: yes. i am also using v3 too. but i want show popup to the user when i got this error code 3, so i am asking this to confirm why it is causing and other possibilities to this same error .

Comment: You dont have google play services installed, or you have to update it". And there is not other possibilities or getting that error. so it means it not happening because of google account not availability.

Comment: nop. indeed, as i wrote in my update, for making it easy for the user you can just say that he has to update the google play application. i think that is the best message you can give. and the only one. you can be sure there is not other reason for that error code

Comment: I am getting this error when i don't have google account in my device

Comment: but if you dont have google acount, you also dont have the google play app updated and running. and the error is for that, not for the account itself

Comment: i go to sleep, i've been 2 hours with this and its late in the morning. I provide all the links and the code so you can be sure that the reason is the package manager doesnt know that service, and you have the information about what that service is, so you can be sure about what is happening and what to tell the user

Comment: did you get enough information, do you have any further doubt we can help with?

Comment: Not yet, i need final statement about this error. what i need to show to the user when i got this error, this is causing because of lack of google account or any other possibilities. because user have to know about this text and need to do action according to this. like if he does't have account he will add or if it is related to updating google play he will update it.

Comment: you can be sure. As i said, the line `getPackageManager().queryIntentServices(serviceIntent, 0)` is asking the packagemanager if the service is available. If it is not, then the function launches that error. That service is available if the user has the last play app and play services running. So for sure you have to as the user to do that. if the user doesnt have a google acount, the google play app wont be running, and the error is for this. If you ask the user to update play app, then it will have to add the google acount and update the app. Thats all you need

Comment: Thank you . i will do as you said in above statement.

Comment: I just add Google Account to device and it works now.

Comment: Error can also be received on non official Android versions

Comment: This answer is wrong. Error 3 can occur if there is no google user logged in on the device.

Answer (score 18):

This error is also received after the user removes their google account from the device.

Comment: I do remove a google account and change another google account. then i reboot the device, It's still show this error, how can i do?

Comment: I'm getting `iabv3: Failed to retrieve info for X products, X` I added an android account in my emulator and the  error went away.

Answer (score 9):

Sign in to the Play Store with any account.

After signing in billing works even on Android Studio Emulator.

Answer (score 7):

Majorly possibility of your issue `BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_BILLING_UNAVAILABLE` is that In some countries still In App Purchase is not allowed like Serbia and many countries.

So Any user from the country where Google Play does not support In App Purchase then You will get `BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_BILLING_UNAVAILABLE`.

This would be less chance that user do not have updated Google Play Service installed on the phone so do not worry about this case.

Comment: Currently i am getting this if user does't have google account in the device

Comment: Yeah This would be case also but mostly user will have configured account. Because Then it is possible they can download your app from the Google Play but majorly is IAB not supported in some countries

Comment: @Williams, do you have any sources were we can check that indeed the error returned in this cases is this one? that error at any range means that the package manager doesn't know that service, so it has to be installed.  If the user cannot install it and the reason is that in that country the user cannot install it, that should be a further message from the device or whoever.

Answer (score 2):

Try this hacks

**Remove the cache, data and updates for the play app, restarted the play app again it should work! or try with latest updates (if it is fixed)**

FYI:

Just keep in mind:

- IABv3 is built into Google Play services, so it requires an update to
  the Play Services apk.
- V2 was built into the Play store client itself. The cache/EULA issue
  isn't specifically related to IAB, it's related to setting up Play
  Services (and hopefully is unnecessary for most users, the cache part
  anyway).
- It's a bummer to be in this transition period where Play Services has
  to be updated before your app can take advantage of it, but I think
  most people would agree that it's better than waiting for an OS
  upgrade.'

See this ref:  [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=41324), [G+ post](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/R8DKwZDsz5m)

Comment: Your answer not related to what i asked here.. i want what are the possibilities to get this error event..

Comment: Clearing the cache of play store works for me. I saw the same answer in [another thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14556878/android-inapp-version-3-error)

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still facing this problem, in most cases iab isn't supported in your country like Williams said. You can use a VPN to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Sometime if you haven't authenticated your device with Google account, may receive this error.

Comment: How to authenticated device?

Answer (score 0):

If you're located in Tonga(as me) or any other country where you're unable to buy apps in Google Play you must use a VPN to test billing. Otherwise you will get this error.