# Android In App Billing "Billing service unavailable on device. (response: 3:Billing Unavailable)"

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I built and android game which has a premium in app purchase, and I had it working fine for a while. (The game was in a beta testing branch, and users could purchase the premium upgrade fine.)

A few days ago I decided to rewrite the project, so I could clean up my code a bit. Everything seemed to work fine. (Play Game Services and AdMob Ads still work) However, in app billing no longer works. Every time my app start I receive an error: `"Billing service unavailable on device. (response: 3:Billing Unavailable)"` I've searched around everywhere, and found plenty of people having this issue, but none of their answers helped me.

**I've tried:**

- Clearing the cache of the Google Play app, and accepting the terms by starting the app.
- Trying multiple users on my phone. (All of which were added to the testers list in the developer console.)
- Testing on at least 3 other (non-rooted) devices.
- Double checking that the `"com.android.vending.BILLING"` permission is in my manifest file.
- Using the same keystore to sign my new application.
- Using the same exact namespace for my new project.
- Trying 3 different play store versions.

**Here is my iabHelper code.**

```
String base64EncodedPublicKey = "KEY HERE";

iabHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);
iabHelper.enableDebugLogging(true);
iabHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
        if (!result.isSuccess()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Problem setting up in-app billing: " + result.getMessage());
            return;
        }

        if (iabHelper == null) return;

        iabHelper.queryInventoryAsync(new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inv) {
                if (iabHelper == null) return;

                if (result.isFailure()) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to query inventory: " + result);
                    return;
                }

                Purchase premiumPurchase = inv.getPurchase("premium");
                isPremium = (premiumPurchase != null);

                if (!premium())
                    loadInterstitial();
           }
        });
    }
});
```

**and my onActivityResult code**

I'm pretty sure this isn't done correctly, however I don't think it's relevant to this error. (This isn't even called before I see the error while debugging.)

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onActivityResult(" + requestCode + "," + resultCode + "," + data);

    // Pass on the activity result to the helper for handling
    if (!iabHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
        if (resultCode == GamesActivityResultCodes.RESULT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED)
            gameHelper.disconnect();
        gameHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "onActivityResult handled by IABUtil.");
    }
}
```

I don't normally like having to ask for help, as the answer is normally accessible online somewhere. However, I've been at this for a few days now, and I've already ripped out all the hair I have. Thanks for any help you can offer.

My best guess at the moment is that I forgot to copy something from the original project, which is causing it to fail, but I can't think of anything besides the base64EncodedPublic key, my keystore, and the use of the same namespace. Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you found an answer? I have the E-X-A-C-T same problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35947832/android-iab-billing-service-unavailable-on-device

Comment: There is also another answer related to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21091353/what-are-the-possibilities-to-get-this-error-code-3-in-inapp-purchase

Comment: Found an answer? Having the same problem.